# Access Conditional Formatting Hatching

Tags: ms-access, vba

Is it possible to include hatching or other such advanced formatting I'm access vba?

The only way I can think to achieve this is overlay an image file over the field or object you want formatted. And have it set to hidden when not required.

However I suspect this might be difficult.

Comment: why do you need hatching, is it possible to use an alternative like the enabled feature?

Comment: We currently use 4 colours already, this is simple to show when a record has not had a specific function performed on it, in addition to the existing conditional formats.